# Minimum of $L[\phi]$ in closed form

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, linear-regression

I recently posted a question about [finding the partial derivatives of a function $L[\phi]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727826/partial-derivative-of-l-phi-with-respect-to-phi-0-and-phi-1). This was Problem 2.1 from Simon Prince's "[Understanding Deep Learning](https://udlbook.github.io/udlbook/)". However, my motivation for doing so was actually because I was confused about the *next* problem:

Show that we can find the minimum of $L[\phi]$ in closed form by setting the expression for the derivatives of $L[\phi]$ to zero and solving for $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$.

$L[\phi] = \sum_{i=1}^I (\phi_0 + \phi_1x_i - y_i)^2$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi_0} = 2 \sum_{i=1}^I (\phi_0 + \phi_1x_i - y_i)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi_1} = 2 \sum_{i=1}^I (\phi_0 + \phi_1x_i - y_i)x_i$

I set both expressions equal to each other and solved for $\phi_0, \ \phi_1$. My attempt led me to the following:

$\phi_0 = \sum_{i=1}^I \frac{\phi_1x_i^2 -y_ix_i +y_i}{x_i +1}$

$\phi_1 = \sum_{i=1}^I \frac{\phi_0 x_i - y_ix_i + y_i - \phi_0}{x^2_i + x_i}$

Doesn't feel correct, can anyone advise? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want to set both partials to 0 rather than just to each other?

Comment: Yes, since they should both be set to 0, I thought I could set them equal to each other, i.e., $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_0} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi_1} = 0$. Perhaps this is not the way to think about it, though...

Comment: There are two conditions rather than 1:  they are both equal to each other and equal to zero.  With just the one condition ("equal to each other") you just get one parameter in terms of the other.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I'll have another look at it

Comment: I tried this but everything cancelled out, which leads me to think that $\phi_0 = \phi_1$...? I can post my attempt if necessary.